# ruby 'best way' to generate 2d array

Tags: ruby

I have create empty array of array like below , Is there any other best way to initialize it ?.

```
arr = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

Comment: but i need the best way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve it by using `Array` class.
ex:

```
Array.new(width){Array.new(height)}
```

you can also provide `width` & `height` value like `width = 2` & `height = 4`

Comment: You have answered a question that was not asked. The OP was specific that the inner arrays are all empty arrays. If they are not necessarily empty they might contain anything, including nested objects, yet you have assumed that they are all the same size and all contain only `nil` objects. You have no basis for that assumption.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think I did gave a proper answer infact more then that. if you look at my last line, I have mentioned about providing a value to height and width. So, I am not sure why that doesn't answer his question in your view.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The OP hasn't mentioned anything about inner arrays beside giving an example So, assuming otherwise would be wrong as well.

Comment: The OP said, "create empty array of array like below", which I take to mean, "create array of empty arrays like below", since the outer array is obviously not empty. What else could "empty" refer to? That's also consistent with the given array.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like

```
   arr = Array.new(9) { Array.new }
```

?

Comment: I dont think that will work for all purpose.

Comment: I wanted to resolve his purpose

Comment: Well he is asking about the 'best way' to generate.

Comment: I haven't seen a better solution yet

Comment: I am not sure if you are getting my point but all i am trying to suggest is that your solution wont work in all scenarios.

Comment: And you haven't tell us which is this scenario. Is a secret?

Comment: Yeah probably its a secret and I am not likely to share it with a person who is obsessed with his own view :)